# How to use Paramiko logging?

Tags: python, logging, ssh, paramiko, python-logging

I'm using Paramiko in Python to run command on a box through SSH. How to use Paramiko logging? I mean force it to make logs (in a file or terminal) and set the log level.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Paramiko names its loggers, so simply:

```
import logging
import paramiko

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger("paramiko").setLevel(logging.WARNING) # for example
```

See the [logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html) for some more examples.

You can also use [`log_to_file`](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/paramiko/util.py#L239) from `paramiko.util` to log directly to a file.

Comment: You also need to specify a log file, e.g. paramiko.util.log_to_file("paramiko.log").

Answer (score 11):

```
paramiko.util.log_to_file("<log_file_path>", level = "WARN")
```