# Python paramiko elliptic curve

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, fabric

i'm using python 2.7.12 on a ubuntu16.04
trying to use the Paramiko package ( just need remote ssh command execution)

my code is

```
   import paramiko


    host = "random_host"
    ssh = paramiko.SSHCLient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(host)
```

and the error i get is:

```
crypthography.exceptions.UnsupportedAlgorithm: this backend does not support this elliptic curve.
```

please help

and if there is a better alternative for just remote ssh commands , do tell ( i tried fabric but it still fails when i try to connect)

Comment: Show us [Paramiko log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27587716/850848) and a full exception callstack. Output of `ssh -v` connecting to the same server may help too.

Answer (score -1):

problem here

1) u are using host in double quotes

Try below code with IP first ,instead of host and let us know if it works

```
import paramiko 
ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('192.168.1.26',port=22,username='root',password='default')
```

Comment: OP can connect, it's the handshake that fails. So it cannot be a problem with DNS resolution.

Comment: @pankaj_mishra i tried still same error. Its not dns also because i try with ip too. Maybe it has something to do with the parameters ssh.connect() gets?