# paramiko ImportError: DLL load failed: The operating system cannot run %1

Tags: python, anaconda, paramiko

I downloaded Anaconda for python usages on windows. I'm using paramiko module for SSH. When i try to do SSH connect using paramiko, i'm getting following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 545, in start_client
raise e
ImportError: DLL load failed: The operating system cannot run %1.
```

I tried setting "C:\Users\*****\Anaconda2\Library\bin" path to the environmental variable. But no use in it. Still the error continuous.

Code snippet:

```
import paramiko
sftpSession = None
sshSession = paramiko.SSHClient()
sshSession.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
sshSession.connect(hostname=hostname,username=username,password=password,timeout=2)
```

Comment: how do you initiate the connection?

Comment: @johnII added code snippet

Comment: Show us [paramiko log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27587716/850848)

Comment: Please find the log in this link https://ufile.io/zkux1

Comment: Append the log to your question.

Comment: It seems that you are missing OpenSSL DLLs `libeay32.dll` and ssleay32.dll` (though in my installation of Python, I do not need them, as the SSL in built-into the Python, but you may have some special Python. I do not know Anaconda).

Comment: Okay. Thks for your views @MartinPrikryl

Comment: in my case it was a second python install, that my IDE prefered. But Paramiko was installed in the second python path... better keep your environment tidy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I uninstalled and reinstalled cryptography package with latest version. Now, SSH connect is working without any errors.

pip uninstall cryptography

pip install cryptography

Comment: This worked for me. Now when I run import paramiko, I don't get that DDL error. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found some advice in [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scrapy-users/8N6V_OGUqtI):

1. Create a new conda environment (i.e.: conda create -n paramiko-env python=3)
2. Activate the environment (activate paramiko-env)
3. Run: conda install -c conda-forge paramiko
   maybe you can try it

Comment: Thks for your advice :)