# Paramiko change breaks "connect" with string passwords between version 2.1 and 2.4 -ish

Tags: python, version, paramiko

This code works (using python) with Paramiko 2.1.2:

```
destination = '192.168.1.2'
user = 'iamtheuser'
myPassword = 'thisisthepassword'

# create ssh connection
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(destination,username=user,password=myPassword)
```

But does *not* work with Paramiko 2.4.1.  The following error is thrown:

```
  File "C:\Users\thisuser\myfilename.py", line 23, in myfunction
    ssh.connect(destination,username=user,password=myPassword)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 424, in connect
    passphrase,
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 701, in _auth
    self._transport.auth_password(username, password)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1376, in aut
h_password
    self.auth_handler.auth_password(username, password, my_event)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\auth_handler.py", line 114, in a
uth_password
    self._request_auth()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\auth_handler.py", line 165, in _
request_auth
    self.transport._send_message(m)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1707, in _se
nd_message
    self.packetizer.send_message(data)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\packet.py", line 385, in send_me
ssage
    out = self.__block_engine_out.update(packet)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers\ba
se.py", line 149, in update
    return self._ctx.update(data)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\ciph
ers.py", line 120, in update
    n = self.update_into(data, buf)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\ciph
ers.py", line 131, in update_into
    "unsigned char *", self._backend._ffi.from_buffer(buf)
TypeError: from_buffer() cannot return the address of the raw string within a by
tes or unicode or bytearray object
```

I've tried looking at the Paramiko changelog (potentially related to [bug 1039](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/1039)?) but quite frankly most of the troubleshooting is over my head. Any thoughts for a part-time programmer?

Log file for version 2.1.2 (works)

```
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.067] thr=1   paramiko.transport: starting thread (client mode): 0x3828828
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.068] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.1.2
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.074] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
    INF [20180501-08:46:58.074] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_5.3)
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.075] thr=1   paramiko.transport: kex algos:['diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256', 'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'] server key:['ssh-rsa', 'ssh-dss'] client encrypt:['aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'arcfour256', 'arcfour128', 'aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'cast128-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'arcfour', 'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se'] server encrypt:['aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'arcfour256', 'arcfour128', 'aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'cast128-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'arcfour', 'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se'] client mac:['hmac-md5', 'hmac-sha1', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-ripemd160', 'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5-96'] server mac:['hmac-md5', 'hmac-sha1', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-ripemd160', 'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5-96'] client compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] server compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.075] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Kex agreed: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.076] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.076] thr=1   paramiko.transport: MAC agreed: hmac-sha2-256
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.076] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Compression agreed: none
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.598] thr=1   paramiko.transport: kex engine KexGroup1 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha1>
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.599] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Switch to new keys ...
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.600] thr=2   paramiko.transport: Adding ssh-rsa host key for <server and passkey removed>
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.641] thr=1   paramiko.transport: userauth is OK
    INF [20180501-08:46:58.695] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Authentication (password) successful!
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.696] thr=2   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.701] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.701] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Secsh channel 0 opened.
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.703] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.817] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] EOF received (0)
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.818] thr=2   paramiko.transport: [chan 1] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.819] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] EOF sent (0)
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.819] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 1] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.819] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Secsh channel 1 opened.
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.860] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 1] Sesch channel 1 request ok
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.983] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 1] EOF received (1)
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.985] thr=3   paramiko.transport: starting thread (client mode): 0x7e17860
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.985] thr=3   paramiko.transport: Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.1.2
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.991] thr=3   paramiko.transport: Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
    INF [20180501-08:46:58.991] thr=3   paramiko.transport: Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_5.3)
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.993] thr=3   paramiko.transport: kex algos:['diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256', 'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'] server key:['ssh-rsa', 'ssh-dss'] client encrypt:['aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'arcfour256', 'arcfour128', 'aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'cast128-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'arcfour', 'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se'] server encrypt:['aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'arcfour256', 'arcfour128', 'aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'cast128-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'arcfour', 'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se'] client mac:['hmac-md5', 'hmac-sha1', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-ripemd160', 'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5-96'] server mac:['hmac-md5', 'hmac-sha1', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-ripemd160', 'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5-96'] client compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] server compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.993] thr=3   paramiko.transport: Kex agreed: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.993] thr=3   paramiko.transport: Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.993] thr=3   paramiko.transport: MAC agreed: hmac-sha2-256
    DEB [20180501-08:46:58.993] thr=3   paramiko.transport: Compression agreed: none
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.011] thr=3   paramiko.transport: kex engine KexGroup1 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha1>
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.012] thr=3   paramiko.transport: Switch to new keys ...
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.013] thr=2   paramiko.transport: Adding ssh-rsa host key for <server and passkey removed>
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.052] thr=3   paramiko.transport: userauth is OK
    INF [20180501-08:46:59.107] thr=3   paramiko.transport: Authentication (password) successful!
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.107] thr=2   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.111] thr=3   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.111] thr=3   paramiko.transport: Secsh channel 0 opened.
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.113] thr=3   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.227] thr=3   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] EOF received (0)
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.227] thr=2   paramiko.transport: [chan 1] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.228] thr=3   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] EOF sent (0)
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.229] thr=3   paramiko.transport: [chan 1] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.229] thr=3   paramiko.transport: Secsh channel 1 opened.
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.270] thr=3   paramiko.transport: [chan 1] Sesch channel 1 request ok
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.394] thr=3   paramiko.transport: [chan 1] EOF received (1)
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.394] thr=3   paramiko.transport: [chan 1] EOF sent (1)
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.395] thr=3   paramiko.transport: EOF in transport thread
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.396] thr=4   paramiko.transport: starting thread (client mode): 0x383a4e0
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.396] thr=4   paramiko.transport: Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.1.2
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.405] thr=4   paramiko.transport: Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
    INF [20180501-08:46:59.405] thr=4   paramiko.transport: Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_5.3)
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.407] thr=4   paramiko.transport: kex algos:['diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256', 'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'] server key:['ssh-rsa', 'ssh-dss'] client encrypt:['aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'arcfour256', 'arcfour128', 'aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'cast128-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'arcfour', 'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se'] server encrypt:['aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'arcfour256', 'arcfour128', 'aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'cast128-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'arcfour', 'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se'] client mac:['hmac-md5', 'hmac-sha1', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-ripemd160', 'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5-96'] server mac:['hmac-md5', 'hmac-sha1', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-ripemd160', 'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5-96'] client compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] server compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.408] thr=4   paramiko.transport: Kex agreed: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.408] thr=4   paramiko.transport: Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.408] thr=4   paramiko.transport: MAC agreed: hmac-sha2-256
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.408] thr=4   paramiko.transport: Compression agreed: none
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.426] thr=4   paramiko.transport: kex engine KexGroup1 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha1>
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.426] thr=4   paramiko.transport: Switch to new keys ...
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.428] thr=2   paramiko.transport: Adding ssh-rsa host key for <server and passkey removed>
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.466] thr=4   paramiko.transport: userauth is OK
    INF [20180501-08:46:59.534] thr=4   paramiko.transport: Authentication (password) successful!
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.535] thr=2   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.540] thr=4   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.540] thr=4   paramiko.transport: Secsh channel 0 opened.
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.543] thr=4   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.706] thr=4   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] EOF received (0)
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.706] thr=2   paramiko.transport: [chan 1] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.707] thr=4   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] EOF sent (0)
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.707] thr=4   paramiko.transport: [chan 1] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.707] thr=4   paramiko.transport: Secsh channel 1 opened.
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.749] thr=4   paramiko.transport: [chan 1] Sesch channel 1 request ok
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.929] thr=4   paramiko.transport: [chan 1] EOF received (1)
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.930] thr=4   paramiko.transport: [chan 1] EOF sent (1)
    DEB [20180501-08:46:59.930] thr=4   paramiko.transport: EOF in transport thread
```

Log file for 2.4.1 (does not work)

```
DEB [20180501-08:48:09.289] thr=1   paramiko.transport: starting thread (client mode): 0x39216d8
DEB [20180501-08:48:09.289] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.4.1
DEB [20180501-08:48:09.289] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
INF [20180501-08:48:09.289] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_5.3)
DEB [20180501-08:48:09.289] thr=1   paramiko.transport: kex algos:['diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256', 'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'] server key:['ssh-rsa', 'ssh-dss'] client encrypt:['aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'arcfour256', 'arcfour128', 'aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'cast128-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'arcfour', 'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se'] server encrypt:['aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'arcfour256', 'arcfour128', 'aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'cast128-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'arcfour', 'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se'] client mac:['hmac-md5', 'hmac-sha1', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-ripemd160', 'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5-96'] server mac:['hmac-md5', 'hmac-sha1', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-ripemd160', 'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5-96'] client compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] server compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
DEB [20180501-08:48:09.289] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Kex agreed: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
DEB [20180501-08:48:09.289] thr=1   paramiko.transport: HostKey agreed: ssh-rsa
DEB [20180501-08:48:09.289] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
DEB [20180501-08:48:09.289] thr=1   paramiko.transport: MAC agreed: hmac-sha2-256
DEB [20180501-08:48:09.289] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Compression agreed: none
DEB [20180501-08:48:09.299] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Got server p (2048 bits)
DEB [20180501-08:48:09.469] thr=1   paramiko.transport: kex engine KexGexSHA256 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
DEB [20180501-08:48:09.469] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Switch to new keys ...
DEB [20180501-08:48:09.469] thr=2   paramiko.transport: Adding ssh-rsa host key for <server and passkey removed>
DEB [20180501-08:48:09.489] thr=1   paramiko.transport: EOF in transport thread
```

Comment: Post Paramiko log file from both versions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27587716/850848

Comment: Added log files

Comment: Did you try forcing `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` (the one that 2.1.2 uses)? E.g. by disabling `diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256` on the server or by editing `_preferred_kex` in Paramiko code?

Comment: pip install --upgrade cryptography solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for my problem was to force the preferred key (thanks to Martin Prikryl for the tip):

```
paramiko.Transport._preferred_kex = ('diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1',)
```

I'm not sure if this qualifies as the correct method or rather a workaround.  To sum up the solution:

```
Paramiko Version   "Agreed" key      Result
Client    Server   
v2.1.2    v2.1.2   diffie...-sha1    Success
v2.4.1    v2.1.2   diffie...-sha256  Fail
v2.4.1    v2.1.2   diffie...-sha1    Success (manually set preferred key)
```