# Paramiko sftp put request getting terminated with EOFError() in python

Tags: linux, python-2.7, ftp, sftp, paramiko

I'm trying to upload couple of .zip files with size ranging between 20 to 30 MBs using python's sftp module 'Paramiko'. I'm able to successfully connect to the sftp server, and also able to list the contents in the destination directory. But while attempting to upload files from my ec2 linux machine, the request is taking too much time and then terminating with EOFError(). Below is the code,

```
>>> import paramiko
>>> import os
>>> ftp_host='*****'
>>> ftp_username='***'
>>> ftp_password='**'
>>> ssh_client=paramiko.SSHClient()
>>> ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
>>> ssh_client.connect(hostname=ftp_host,username=ftp_username,password=ftp_password, timeout=500)
>>> ftp_client=ssh_client.open_sftp()
>>> ftp_client.chdir('/inbound/')
>>> ftp_client.listdir()
[u't5-file-1.zip', u'edp_r.zip', u'T5_Transaction_Sample.gz']
>>> ftp_client.put("/path-to-zip-files-on-local/edp_revenue.zip","/inbound/edp_revenue.zip")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 669, in put
    return self.putfo(fl, remotepath, file_size, callback, confirm)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 626, in putfo
    fr.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/file.py", line 331, in write
    self._write_all(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/file.py", line 448, in _write_all
    count = self._write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/sftp_file.py", line 176, in _write
    self._reqs.append(self.sftp._async_request(type(None), CMD_WRITE, self.handle, long(self._realpos), data[:chunk]))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 750, in _async_request
    self._send_packet(t, msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/sftp.py", line 170, in _send_packet
    self._write_all(out)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/sftp.py", line 135, in _write_all
    raise EOFError()
EOFError
```

When I'm trying the same thing using curl command I'm easily able to do and just in 20 seconds. What am I missing here? Is it the size which is making the request to timed out or anything else.

Comment: Can post [Paramiko log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27587716/850848)? You should probably also update your copy of Paramiko. It looks like you are not using the latest version. + Show us `curl` command that you use.

Comment: It seems I was using an older version of paramiko on my linux machine. i upgraded it using pip and then re-run everthing. Now it's working. Thanks @Martin.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was using an older version of paramiko on my linux server. I upgraded it using,

```
 pip install --upgraded paramiko
```

and then logged everything in a log file,

```
paramiko.util.log_to_file('/path_to_log_file/paramiko.log')
```

just to capture every detail. Now it seems to be working pretty fast and correct.