# How do I troubleshoot spur failing to make an SSH connection in python?

Tags: python, debugging, ssh, paramiko

I have two nearly identical devices. spur will connect via ssh with one, but not the other. How do I figure out why?

```
>>> shell1 = spur.SshShell('10.201.140.242', 'username', 'password', missing_host_key=spur.ssh.MissingHostKey.accept)
>>> results = shell1.run(['ls', '-a'])
>>> results.output
'.\n..\n.aptitude\n.bashrc\n.cache\n.config\n.profile\n'

>>> shell2 = spur.SshShell('10.201.129.56', 'username', 'password', missing_host_key=spur.ssh.MissingHostKey.accept)
>>> results = shell2.run(['ls', '-a'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\development\virtenv\lib\site-packages\spur\ssh.py", line 166, in run
return self.spawn(*args, **kwargs).wait_for_result()
  File "E:\development\virtenv\lib\site-packages\spur\ssh.py", line 178, in spawn
channel = self._get_ssh_transport().open_session()
  File "E:\development\virtenv\lib\site-packages\spur\ssh.py", line 268, in _get_ssh_transport
raise self._connection_error(error)
ConnectionError: Error creating SSH connection
Original error: ('10.201.129.56', <paramiko.ecdsakey.ECDSAKey object at 0x11328070>, <paramiko.ecdsakey.ECDSAKey object at 0x1135F350>)
```

I'm confused by the error message. What does returning the ip, and two key objects supposed to mean? Is there helpful info here I'm supposed to glean from that?

Both devices will accept ssh connections from the command line, so that sets aside an obvious problem.

Both are running the same version of Ubuntu, with the same login credentials. Home directories are even the same (no .ssh dir). Even further, both of their sshd_config files are identical (so, also using the same version among other config options).

The problem doesn't seem to be in the ssh settings, but the error gives no indication of where the problem could be!

Any ideas?

---

Enabling logging doesn't add much.

shell1:

`11:32:11|[    INFO] - paramiko.transport - _log - Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_5.9p1)
11:32:11|[    INFO] - paramiko.transport - _log - Authentication (password) successful!`

shell2:

`11:32:25|[    INFO] - paramiko.transport - _log - Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_5.9p1)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
      File "E:\development\virtenv\lib\site-packages\spur\ssh.py", line 166, in run
    return self.spawn(*args, **kwargs).wait_for_result()
      File "E:\development\virtenv\lib\site-packages\spur\ssh.py", line 178, in spawn
      File "E:\development\virtenv\lib\site-packages\spur\ssh.py", line 268, in _get_ssh_transport
        raise self._connection_error(error)
    ConnectionError: Error creating SSH connection
    Original error: ('10.201.129.56', <paramiko.ecdsakey.ECDSAKey object at 0x1132EF10>, <paramiko.ecdsakey.ECDSAKey object at 0x11366DF0>)`

It might be telling that the SSH reports connection. The failure occurs before/during authentication. But as I said above, the passwords are the same -- both connections even use the same copy-pasted pw, which works without error on a command line connection.

Comment: [Enable logging in Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27587716/850848) and post a log file:

Comment: Well, I discovered that using the network domain of the device allows a connection no problem. It just doesn't like IP for some reason! (again, for "shell2" of the software, shell1, almost identical, has no problem with ip).