# paramiko exception : incompatible ssh peer (no acceptable kex algorithm)

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

Am trying to make a connection to a remote machine, I see this issue with only few machines... I searched thoroughly in stack overflow, didnt find the exact fix for the same.

This is the detailed error:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "paramiko.transport"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ffe_sanity.py", line 199, in <module>
    ffeobj = ffe_sanity(hostname, hostuser, td_host_password)
  File "./ffe_sanity.py", line 114, in __init__
    self.client.connect(td_host_name, username=td_host_user, password=td_host_password)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 265, in connect
    t.start_client()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 406, in start_client
    raise e
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Incompatible ssh peer (no acceptable kex algorithm
```

Comment: Show us Paramiko log file: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27587716/850848

Answer (score 1):

When connecting to some older Cisco devices, I have to add a section like this to my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host 10.1.2.3
    KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    Ciphers +aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
```