# problem with 2 step authentication for a SSH connection in Paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko

I want to connect to a device via SSH with Paramiko (python library) but my device needs 2 step connection as below picture:

[image]

here is my code :

```py
import paramiko
ssh_client =paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname='10.240.235.167',username='cli', password='')


stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command('admin')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command('Admin123\n')
stdin.write('admin123\n')
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh_client.exec_command('my command')
```

but it's not working,
I want to know how to connect and store result of my command.

Comment: what is not working? Please share the error or stacktrace you have got.

Comment: UserWarning: implicit cast from 'char *' to a different pointer type: will be forbidden in the future (check that the types are as you expect; use an explicit ffi.cast() if they are correct)
  self._backend._ffi.from_buffer(data), len(data)
[]

Comment: my problem is first I should  login as cli and I don't know how to implement it with paramiko

Comment: ssh_client.connect(hostname='cli@10.240.235.167',username='admin', password='Admin123')
this will bring:
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed

Comment: 'cli@10.240.235.167` is not a hostname. Use the code from your question -- Your server possibly uses `None` authentication "type". Paramiko does not support that directly. See [Paramiko - Bad Authentication Type [Cisco SG-300 Switch\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53595644/850848). --- If you need more help, you will will have to provide us more information, including logs files (or both Paramiko and some SSH client)

Comment: actually connection is ok after below line
ssh_client.connect(hostname='10.240.235.167',username='cli', password='')
but I don't know how to enter username and password after this line.

Comment: That's what my answer to the question linked in my first comment above shows.

Comment: that's right @MartinPrikryl, but my result is still empty after this change

```python
import paramiko
ssh_client =paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname='10.240.235.167',username='cli', password='')

print ('running remote command')

channel = ssh_client.invoke_shell()
channel.send("admin" + "\n")
channel.send("Admin123" + "\n")

stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh_client.exec_command("show config common licenses" + "\n")

print (stdout.readlines())
```

result:
running remote command
[]

Comment: My answer also explains that you cannot use `exec_command` and shows that you need to send the command to the "shell".

Comment: ok, now I'm use channel.send(command + "\n") , how about answer? should I use channel.recv()?
how can I store the result in a variable?
for example with telnetlib I was able to store result with below code.
status = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST,23,5).read_all().decode('ascii')

Comment: I have added an example code to my answer.

Comment: Yes, your example fixed my problem.
just another question, when I use it in a multi thread way the results will be incomplete and seems that there is a problem with time.sleep(5).
can I ask it from you in another subject?

Comment: Post a new question with [mcve].