# Paramiko with Username & Password, No key - Oops, unhandled type 3 ('unimplemented')

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to SSH into a remote server using Paramiko with Python with a username and password but no key with the following code. For some reason, I am getting an error - `Oops, unhandled type 3 ('unimplemented')`.

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('18.28.xx.xx', username='user', password='password')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls')
stdout.readlines()
ssh.close()
```

When I add `print(ssh.get_transport().is_active())` after `ssh.connect` it returns `True`, which leads me to believe I am actually connected over SSH.  Regardless, I get this error when I try to run any command.

Any ideas on why this doesn't work? Thanks!

Comment: What line of code is triggering the exception? Could you [edit] your question to include the stacktrace?

Comment: I'm running in ipython so I am not getting a stack trace. However, it is the stdin, stdout line that triggers the exception

Comment: Post a [Paramiko log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27587716/850848).