# Getting Oops, unhandled type 3 ('unimplemented') while connecting SFTP with Paramiko

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko

Im trying to make the below script work, so as to read a list of CSV files in a specific directory and from a remote server(server 1) and Port the   data into a PostgreSQL database of another server.

I have created a rsa SSH Key and copied it to the remote server,Now i'm able to connect the server using user name only.

I have tried copying the rsa Pub key/private key to a folder(.ssh folder is not taking while i run the PY script) and gave it's location, even tried pasting the whole private key but it is not working and below exception is raised.

I'm getting error in this line "**sftp = t.open_sftp_client()**", But no useful information is showing in the error.

*Can anyone please help me with,  Suggestions will be very helpful.*

**Exception:**

```
    Database connected
SFTP Connected
Oops, unhandled type 3 ('unimplemented')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sandeep/Documents/paramiko test.py", line 45, in <module>
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 165, in from_transport
    window_size=window_size, max_packet_size=max_packet_size
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 879, in open_session
    timeout=timeout,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1006, in open_channel
    raise e
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2055, in run
    ptype, m = self.packetizer.read_message()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 459, in read_message
    header = self.read_all(self.__block_size_in, check_rekey=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 303, in read_all
    raise EOFError()
EOFError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sandeep/Documents/paramiko test.py", line 50, in <module>
    self._logger.error(msg)
```

**Code:**

```
import paramiko
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
import os
import inspect
import re
import sys

SECTION_SRC_STAR = "DEFAULT"

SSH_HOST = '*****.com'
SSH_USERNAME = 'root'
#SSH_KEYFILE = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.split(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))[0], "ssh.key")))
#SSH_KEYFILE = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.split(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))[0], "id_rsa")))
SSH_KEYFILE ="/Users/sand/Documents/ssh_pub"

SSH_DIR = '/opt/prod_odoo_out/carrierfiles/dhl/'
SSH_PORT = 22
SSH_MASK = 'file_pattern.*\.csv'

DSN = "dbname='postgres' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='postgres' port='5432'"
TABLE_NAME = 'staging.dhl_tracking_details'


conn = psycopg2.connect(DSN)
print("Database connected")
conn.set_client_encoding('latin-1')
cur = conn.cursor()

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
t = paramiko.Transport((SSH_HOST, SSH_PORT))


#key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(SSH_KEYFILE)
#key='***************...........'
#t.connect(username=SSH_USERNAME, pkey=key)
t.connect(username=SSH_USERNAME)
print("SFTP Connected")
try:
    #sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t) 
    sftp = t.open_sftp_client()
    print("SFTP Client : Open")
except Exception as e:
    msg = "Error connecting via ssh: %s" % e
    self._logger.error(msg)
    raise paramiko.SSHException(msg)


for filename in sftp.listdir(SSH_DIR):
    if re.match(SSH_MASK, filename):
        path = '/%s/%s' % (SSH_DIR, filename)
        fobj = sftp.file(path, 'rb')
        #cur.execute('TRUNCATE TABLE %s' % TABLE_NAME)
        #fobj2 = RowsIO(fobj)
        #cur.copy_expert("COPY %s FROM STDOUT WITH DELIMITER ';' NULL 'null' CSV HEADER" % (TABLE_NAME, ), fobj2)
        sql = "COPY %s FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER AS ';'  csv header"
        table = 'staging.dhl_tracking_details'
        cur.copy_expert(sql=sql % table, file=fobj)
        conn.commit()
        sftp.remove(path)

t.close()
```

Comment: @Thomas The exception happens after authentication, so it's unlikely that it has anything to do with private key.

Comment: @Sandeep Can you actually connect to that server using any (GUI/command-line) SFTP client? + Can you post [Paramiko log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27587716/850848)?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yeah, my mistake. I somehow missed the `t.connect` line. Looks like it's using an SSH agent and authentication works.

Answer (score 5):

I have mentioned the RSA key with Pkey attribute and the issue got resolved.

```
pk=paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(open('/Users/sandeep/Documents/ssh_pub/id_rsa'))
t.connect(username=SSH_USERNAME,pkey=pk)
```