# pysftp paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes

Tags: sftp, paramiko, pysftp, ed25519

I am using pysftp for the first time. I have seen this error before with struct and other libraries, but the problem with pysftp seems tricky. I can't connect to the server. I am sure I am missing something basic here, and so any ideas will be helpful.

My code to connect is simply:

```
pysftp.Connection(host=host_name, username='user_name',private_key_pass='pvt_pass',private_key='path/id_ed25519',cnopts=cnopts)
```

I keep getting this error

```
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
```

From reading, I figured that paramiko might need a special `paramiko.Ed25519Key.from_private_key_file` method for 25519 system

However, I don't know how to make pysftp work with it

Comment: Please post full stack trace + [Paramiko log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27587716/850848) + Explain why do you think that the problem is related to Ed25519.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?