# paramiko transport Authentication (password) failed

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, pysftp

I'm trying to pull some files through sftp with pysftp from a kubernetes instance (GKE) but after connecting to the server:

INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client 9.99)

it throws this error:

INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (password) failed.

I've checked the password and it is correct, and I also think the hostkey is OK since the transport connects to the external server.

Comment: Please post a [Paramiko log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27587716/850848) + Log file of any commandline/GUI SFTP client that can successfully authenticate using the same credentials from the same local machine that runs your Python code.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl these are the logs running locally with the same credentials and hostkey:
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client 9.99)
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (password) successful!

INFO:paramiko.transport.sftp:[chan 0] Opened sftp connection (server version 3)

INFO:paramiko.transport.sftp:[chan 0] sftp session closed.

Comment: Please do not add logs on comments as it is limited, add the logs on your post by editing it for a better view. You might also consider checking [this thread](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/391).