# Paramiko SFTP connection not working when venv is activated

Tags: python-3.x, paramiko, private-key, python-venv

Using this code whilst venv is activated returns the exception: `paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.`

```
self.key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(self.path_to_key, password=self.password)
self.client = paramiko.SSHClient()
self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
self.client.connect(hostname=self.hostname, username=self.username, pkey=self.key)
```

But using the exact same code (pkey and password) without activating my venv works as expected.

Why does activating the virtual environment lead to not being able to authenticate my ssh-key?
In the no venv scenario it seems paramiko falls back to a key in ~/.ssh/ rather than using the key provided in the code..

The paramiko debug output (venv):

```
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0x200a9730
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.11.0
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.13
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_6.6.1p1)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:=== Key exchange possibilities ===
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex algos: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org, ecdh-sha2-nistp256, ecdh-sha2-nistp384, ecdh-sha2-nistp521, diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256, diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1, diffie-hellman-group14-sha1, diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server key: ssh-rsa, ssh-dss, ecdsa-sha2-nistp256, ssh-ed25519
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client encrypt: aes128-ctr, aes192-ctr, aes256-ctr, arcfour256, arcfour128, aes128-gcm@openssh.com, aes256-gcm@openssh.com, chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com, aes128-cbc, 3des-cbc, blowfish-cbc, cast128-cbc, aes192-cbc, aes256-cbc, arcfour, rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server encrypt: aes128-ctr, aes192-ctr, aes256-ctr, arcfour256, arcfour128, aes128-gcm@openssh.com, aes256-gcm@openssh.com, chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com, aes128-cbc, 3des-cbc, blowfish-cbc, cast128-cbc, aes192-cbc, aes256-cbc, arcfour, rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client mac: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com, umac-64-etm@openssh.com, umac-128-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com, hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com, hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com, hmac-md5, hmac-sha1, umac-64@openssh.com, umac-128@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-256, hmac-sha2-512, hmac-ripemd160, hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com, hmac-sha1-96, hmac-md5-96
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server mac: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com, umac-64-etm@openssh.com, umac-128-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com, hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com, hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com, hmac-md5, hmac-sha1, umac-64@openssh.com, umac-128@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-256, hmac-sha2-512, hmac-ripemd160, hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com, hmac-sha1-96, hmac-md5-96
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client compress: none, zlib@openssh.com
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server compress: none, zlib@openssh.com
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client lang: <none>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server lang: <none>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex follows: False
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:=== Key exchange agreements ===
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:HostKey: ssh-ed25519
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Cipher: aes128-ctr
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:MAC: hmac-sha2-256
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Compression: none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:=== End of kex handshake ===
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex engine KexCurve25519 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Switch to new keys ...
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Adding ssh-ed25519 host key for www.example.nl: b'0d5077e28f52b8easdfsecafd54d117ced0'
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying SSH key b'fb4313fdsg60117bfda0f63a9271c10'
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Finalizing pubkey algorithm for key of type 'ssh-rsa'
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Our pubkey algorithm list: ['rsa-sha2-512', 'rsa-sha2-256', 'ssh-rsa']
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Server did not send a server-sig-algs list; defaulting to our first preferred algo ('rsa-sha2-512')
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:NOTE: you may use the 'disabled_algorithms' SSHClient/Transport init kwarg to disable that or other algorithms if your server does not support them!
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  ...
  File "/Users/app/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/auth_handler.py", line 259, in wait_for_response
    raise e
paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
```

*EDIT*:
The paramiko debug output (no venv):

````
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0x23873a60
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.7.2
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.13
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_6.6.1p1)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex algos:['curve25519-sha256@libssh.org', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp256', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp384', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp521', 'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256', 'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'] server key:['ssh-rsa', 'ssh-dss', 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256', 'ssh-ed25519'] client encrypt:['aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'arcfour256', 'arcfour128', 'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', 'aes256-gcm@openssh.com', 'chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com', 'aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'cast128-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'arcfour', 'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se'] server encrypt:['aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'arcfour256', 'arcfour128', 'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', 'aes256-gcm@openssh.com', 'chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com', 'aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'cast128-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'arcfour', 'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se'] client mac:['hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-64-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-128-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-md5', 'hmac-sha1', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'umac-128@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-ripemd160', 'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5-96'] server mac:['hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-64-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-128-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-md5', 'hmac-sha1', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'umac-128@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-ripemd160', 'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5-96'] client compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] server compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Kex agreed: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:HostKey agreed: ssh-ed25519
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:MAC agreed: hmac-sha2-256
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Compression agreed: none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex engine KexCurve25519 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Switch to new keys ...
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Adding ssh-ed25519 host key for www.example.nl: b'0d5077e28sdfsfg8eaaecafd54d117ced0'
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying SSH key b'fb43133034a60gjghkka0f63a9271c10'
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) failed.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying discovered key b'72d605sdfsgbb7ebd80292152cbaed21' in /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) successful!
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Secsh channel 0 opened.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
INFO:paramiko.transport.sftp:[chan 0] Opened sftp connection (server version 3)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0x23873af0
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.7.2
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.13
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_6.6.1p1)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex algos:['curve25519-sha256@libssh.org', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp256', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp384', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp521', 'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256', 'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'] server key:['ssh-rsa', 'ssh-dss', 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256', 'ssh-ed25519'] client encrypt:['aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'arcfour256', 'arcfour128', 'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', 'aes256-gcm@openssh.com', 'chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com', 'aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'cast128-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'arcfour', 'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se'] server encrypt:['aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'arcfour256', 'arcfour128', 'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', 'aes256-gcm@openssh.com', 'chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com', 'aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'cast128-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'arcfour', 'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se'] client mac:['hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-64-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-128-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-md5', 'hmac-sha1', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'umac-128@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-ripemd160', 'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5-96'] server mac:['hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-64-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-128-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-md5', 'hmac-sha1', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'umac-128@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-ripemd160', 'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5-96'] client compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] server compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Kex agreed: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:HostKey agreed: ssh-ed25519
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:MAC agreed: hmac-sha2-256
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Compression agreed: none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex engine KexCurve25519 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Switch to new keys ...
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Adding ssh-ed25519 host key for www.example.nl: b'0d5077e28f52b8eaaecafd54d117ced0'
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying SSH key b'fb43133034a601ghjhgda0f63a9271c10'
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) failed.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying discovered key b'72d6052ghjhg41bb7ebd80292152cbaed21' in /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) successful!
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Secsh channel 0 opened.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
INFO:paramiko.transport.sftp:[chan 0] Opened sftp connection (server version 3)```
````

Comment: Post [Paramiko logs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27587716/850848) for both scenarios.